# Running the server in Local Machine without showing cmd the window

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, host

I' ve created my node.js app with express, now i want to upload it on my local server machine.
I've created a bat file (I will use task planner to run this) that basically move to folder app and launch "npm run start".

The question is: There's a more correct way to this? (no cloud) and is it possible to hide the cmd window?

Comment: Install it as a service.

Answer (score 1):

Putting a node.js application to production can be done with [**pm2**](https://pm2.keymetrics.io). Pm2 will spin up your application and keep it alive, without having any terminal/cmd open.

Simply install pm2 globally on your machine:

```
$ npm install pm2 -g
```

Then launch your application with pm2:

```
$ pm2 start app.js
```

There are some configurations you could do, so I suggest you look at their [repo](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)

Comment: Is this the most efficient way?

Comment: @Noob_Programmer I would say no, because you have another tool that can be done with on-board things.No need for pm2, just install your node.js app as service. Thats what services are for...